# How do I get the data results from Invoke-RestMethod into CSV file?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the results (data) from a REST call into a CSV file.

My code is:

```
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Header $bearer -ContentType 'application/json' 
$results
```

and it comes back with:

```
data                                                                                                             
----                                                                                                             
{@{type=flight-offer; id=1559566119876--1838046263; offerItems=System.Object[]}, @{type=flight-offer; id=15595...
```

I want to get the values from each offerItems object into a CSV file.

Answer (score 4):

Expand the `data` property and export the nested objects to a CSV:

```
$results |
    Select-Object -Expand data |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

However, since your data objects apparently contain an array (`offerItems=System.Object[]`) you'll have to mangle that array into a string first, e.g. like this:

```
... |
    Select-Object -Expand data |
    Select-Object *,@{n='offerItems';e={$_.offerItems -join ','}} -Exclude offerItems |
    ...
```

The merge operation may differ depending on what kind of data the array holds.

Comment: What if I want to store offerItems and one more column are System.Object[] and want to store in different columns?